# Creating a file inside a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, directory-structure

I'm currently creating a script that has 2 modes: one for creating files, another for creating folders.

What I currently have when it comes to creating files is:

```
elif mode == "B":
    fileName = input("What's the name of the file you'd like to create? ")
    filePath = input("Where would you like this file to go? ")
    if not os.path.exists(fileName):
        f = open(fileName, "x")
        print("File", fileName, "created")
    else:
        print("File", fileName, "already exists")
```

As is, it creates the file on the same directory of the .py script. How could I make it create inside the directory specified at `filePath = input("Where would you like this file to go? ")`(assuming it exists) and throwing an error in case said directory does not currently exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.join()`:

```
final_file_name = os.path.join(filePath, fileName)
```

The path must exist, or you can create it beforehand with

```
os.makedirs(filePath, exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: Actually, that last part for creating the directory in case it does not exist is something I planned to add as: if the user tries to create the file on a non-existent directory, it'll ask them if they'd like to create the directory and the file together.

Answer (score 1):

Before the `if not os.path.exists(...)` you could check if `filePath` exists and if not create it with `os.mkdir(filePath)`

Answer (score 0):

In order, you should check that the file path exists(if not create it), then check if the file exists, then create the file.

```
# This will check if the filePath doesn't exists, then create it if it doesn't exist:
if not os.path.exists(filepath):
    os.makedirs(filePath)
```

Next, check if the file exists in the correct path.

```
filePath = './'
fileName = 'test.py'

# Checks if file exists w/ an else exception, so you fill in what you want to do
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(filePath, fileName)):
    # Do something if the file already exists
    print('file already exists')
else:
    # Create file
    print('file doesn\'t exists')
```